# Bijection morphism to be isomorphism?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, birational-geometry

Let $S$ be a smooth projective surface. $Bl_p(S)$ be the blow up of $S$ at a point $P$. Let $Y$ be a variety. If we have: $f:Bl_p(S)\to Y$, $g:Y\to S$ such taht $f\circ g$ is the natural projection, and $f$ is a bijection, can we conclude that $f$ is an isomorphism?

Thank you!

Addition related to comment below: I was aware of the excellent linked post. However, one key ingredient missing here is the normality of $Y$. I am wondering if the additional information in my situation can make up for the loss of normality here.

Comment: See also https://mathoverflow.net/questions/73321/isomorphism-between-varieties-of-char-0

Comment: look at the restriction of $f$ to inverse image of $U = S\setminus p$, call it $f_U$. Then $f_U$ is bijective but on $U$ the domain of $f_U$ is just $U$ and hence the structure map $Y_U \rightarrow U$ becomes a bijective map and $U$ is clearly normal and hence $f_U$ is an isomorphism. Thus $Y$ is nothing but the blowup along $I$ with support $p$(follows from hartshorne exercise 7.11 chapter 2). Since blowup along $I$ and $\sqrt{I}$ is same we get that $Y$ is nothing but blowup along $p$. Now universal property of blowup implies that the map $f$ is an isomorphism.